# how to match string stored in shared preferences with current date

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app i am storing a 2 dimensional array using shared prefernces which contains dates now i have to match the array dates with current date 
     the whole thing is on public void `onrecieve()`

At the time of saving it gives me no error but when i match current date with arrays date it always show false doesnt matter what is the date and it never goes in the if condition

```
String[][] my_date;
Set<String> checkDate;

/* getting today date and coverting it into string */
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
int todaysDate = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
String cDate = Integer.toString(todaysDate);

SharedPreferences pref = arg0.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < my_date.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < my_date[i].length; j++){
        set.add("'" + my_date[i][j] + "'"); 
        Log.v("dates", my_date[i][j]);
    }
}
editor.putStringSet("dates", set);
editor.commit();

checkDate = pref.getStringSet("dates", set);

if(checkDate.contains(cDate)){
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(arg0,DialogActivity.class); 
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    arg0.startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

Comment: What does logging `cDate` and `my_date[i][j]` print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will give you `false` always. You put day numbers to the set with apostrophes. So, your `Set` will have items like: `'1', '2', '3'`. Whilst `String` representation of `cDate` has no such apostrophes, so `String.valueOf(1)` is not equal `"'1'"`. Try to replace this:

```
set.add("'" + my_date[i][j] + "'");
```

with this:

```
set.add(my_date[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding a `'` before and after your adding the String to the set. change this to the following to only store the date. Than your Strings should be equal:

```
set.add(my_date[i][j]);//instead of set.add("'" + my_date[i][j] + "'");
```